# Angular run method only on redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to Angular and am quite confused about routes.  I am using Asp.Net MVC.  I have a method in my Angular controller that I only want executed when the page first opens which comes from a redirect from the Home Page.  Is there a way to do this?  I thought I had this figured out, but the method executes on every postback and I need it to only execute when the page first opens.  My method is:

```
getSearch();
function getSearch() {
    generalsearchService.getSearch()
    .success(function (data) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data.SearchResults;
    });
};
```

I use the getSearch above to call an ActionResult in my MVC controller via Angular Service, because I was trying to do a work around on a previous issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509516/angular-redirect-results-to-another-mvc-view.  The work around seemed to work fine, until I tried to execute a "normal" search on the page and click the Search button, which goes back to the MVC Controller to get the searching using the parameters the user has selected in the search page.  For whatever reason, having the getSearch() code above stops the SubmitSearch from working properly.

Here is my entire Angular controller code:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('GeneralSearchCtrl', function ($scope, generalsearchService) {
    $scope.oneAtATime = true;

    $scope.selected_Services = [];
    $scope.picked_Areas = [];
    $scope.required_Verifications = [];
    $scope.subscribed_Subscriptions = [];
    $scope.form = {};

    getSearch();
    function getSearch() {
        generalsearchService.getSearch()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.gridOptions.data = data.SearchResults;
        });
    };
    $scope.gridOptions = {

        enableFiltering: true,
        paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
        paginationPageSize: 25,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        exporterCsvFilename: 'myFile.csv',
        exporterPdfDefaultStyle: { fontSize: 9 },
        exporterPdfTableStyle: { margin: [30, 30, 30, 30] },
        exporterPdfTableHeaderStyle: { fontSize: 10, bold: true, italics: true, color: 'red' },
        exporterPdfHeader: { text: "My Header", style: 'headerStyle' },
        exporterPdfFooter: function (currentPage, pageCount) {
            return { text: currentPage.toString() + ' of ' + pageCount.toString(), style: 'footerStyle' };
        },
        exporterPdfCustomFormatter: function (docDefinition) {
            docDefinition.styles.headerStyle = { fontSize: 22, bold: true };
            docDefinition.styles.footerStyle = { fontSize: 10, bold: true };
            return docDefinition;
        },
        exporterPdfOrientation: 'portrait',
        exporterPdfPageSize: 'LETTER',
        exporterPdfMaxGridWidth: 500,
        exporterCsvLinkElement: angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location")),
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        }

    };

    getServices();
    function getServices() {
        generalsearchService.getAllServices()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.services = data;
        });
    };
    getAreas();
    function getAreas() {
        generalsearchService.getAreas()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.areas = data;
        });
    };
    getVerifications();
    function getVerifications() {
        generalsearchService.getVerifications()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.verifications = data;
        });
    };

    getSubscriptions();
    function getSubscriptions() {
        generalsearchService.getSubscriptions()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.subscriptions = data;
        });
    };

    getCompanyTypes();
    function getCompanyTypes() {
        generalsearchService.getCompanyTypes()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.contractorTypes = data;
        });
    };

    getBusinessUnits();
    function getBusinessUnits() {
        generalsearchService.getBusinessUnits()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.businessUnits = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.form.selected = {
        services: []
    };

    $scope.form.required = {
        verifications: []
    };
    $scope.addService = function (service, checked) {

        var idx = $scope.form.selected.services.indexOf(service);

        if (idx >= 0 && !checked) {

            $scope.selected_Services.splice(idx, 1);
            $scope.form.selected.services.splice(idx, 1);

        }
        if (idx < 0 && checked) {
            //$scope.selected_Services.push(angular.copy(service));
            $scope.form.selected.services.push(service);
            $scope.selected_Services.push(angular.copy(service));
        }

    };


    $scope.addVerification = function (verification, checked) {
        var idx = $scope.form.required.verifications.indexOf(verification);
        if (idx >= 0 && !checked) {
            $scope.form.required.verifications.splice(idx, 1);
            $scope.required_Verifications.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        if (idx < 0 && checked) {
            $scope.form.required.verifications.push(verification);
            $scope.required_Verifications.push(angular.copy(verification));
        }
    };



    $scope.form.picked = {
        areas: []
    };

    $scope.form.getAreas = function () {
        return $scope.form.picked.areas;
    };

    $scope.addArea = function (area, checked) {

        var idx = $scope.form.picked.areas.indexOf(area);
        if (idx >= 0 && !checked) {
            $scope.form.picked.areas.splice(idx, 1);
            $scope.picked_Areas.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        if (idx < 0 && checked) {
            $scope.form.picked.areas.push(area);
            $scope.picked_Areas.push(angular.copy(area));
        }
    };

    $scope.form.getSubscriptions = function () {
        return $scope.form.subscribed.subscriptions;
    };

    $scope.addSubscription = function (subscription, checked) {
        var idx = $scope.form.subscribed.subscriptions.indexOf(subscription);
        if (idx >= 0 && !checked) {
            $scope.form.subscribed.subscriptions.splice(idx, 1);
            $scope.subscribed_Subscriptions.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        if (idx < 0 && checked) {
            $scope.form.subscribed.subscriptions.push(subscription);
            $scope.subscribed_Subscriptions.push(angular.copy(subscription));
        }
    }

    $scope.form.subscribed = {
        subscriptions: []
    };

    $scope.getBUContractors = function () {
        debugger;
        unitId = $scope.form.OperatorBusinessUnitID;
        generalsearchService.getContractorsByBU(unitId)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.companies = data;
            $scope.totalItems = $scope.companies.length;

        });
    };

    $scope.form.getContractors = function () {
        return $scope.form.selected.services;
    };

    $scope.submit2 = function () {
        $scope.form.Services = [];
        $scope.form.Areas = [];
        $scope.form.Verifications = [];
        $scope.form.Subscriptions = [];

        if ($scope.form.Services != null) {
            for (x in $scope.selected_Services)
                $scope.form.Services.push($scope.selected_Services[x].ServiceID);
        };
        if ($scope.form.Areas != null) {
            for (y in $scope.picked_Areas)
                $scope.form.Areas.push($scope.picked_Areas[y].StateVchID);
        };
        if ($scope.form.Verifications != null) {
            for (z in $scope.required_Verifications)
                $scope.form.Verifications.push($scope.required_Verifications[z].VerificationTypeID);
        };
        if ($scope.form.Subscriptions != null) {
            for (i in $scope.subscribed_Subscriptions)
                $scope.form.Subscriptions.push($scope.subscribed_Subscriptions[i].SubsriptionTypeID);
        };

        generalsearchService.submitSearch($scope.form)
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.gridOptions.data = data.SearchResults;
            //$scope.companies = data.SearchResults;
            //$scope.totalItems = data.Count;
            //$location.path('/SSQV4/SSQV5/GeneralSearch')
            //$scope.gridOptions.data = data;

        });
    };

    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 25;
    $scope.maxSize = 5; //Number of pager buttons to show

    $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
        //if($scope.currentPage == 41)
        //{

        //}
    };

    $scope.setItemsPerPage = function (num) {
        $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first paghe
    };

    $scope.status = {
        isFirstOpen: true,
        isFirstDisabled: false
    };




});
```

Here is my MVC Controller Code:

```
 public ActionResult GetSearch()
        {

            strSqlQuery = " LEFT JOIN tblTrainingRelease TR on C.CompanyID = TR.ContractorID and TR.OperatorID = " + MajorID + " AND TR.bitContractorRelease = 1 and TR.bitReleaseGranted = 1 " +
                            " LEFT JOIN tblSSQReleaseToMajor (READUNCOMMITTED) ON C.CompanyID = RT.CompanyID AND RT.MajorID = " + MajorID + " WHERE 1 = 1";

            strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " AND ((C.vchCompanyName like '%" + SearchString + "%') OR (isnull(C.vchFIDNumber, '') like '%" + SearchString + "%') OR (convert(varchar(16), C.CompanyID) like '%" + SearchString + "%'))";
            strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " ORDER BY c.vchCompanyName";
            if (SearchString != "")
            {
                var results = SearchClient.PostGeneralSearch(strSqlQuery, 1000, 1);
                return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                SearchString = "";

            }
            else
            {
                return View("GeneralSearch");

            }

        }
 public ActionResult SubmitCriteria(ContractorSearchViewModel form)
        {


            int i;
            int businessUnitID = 0;
            int servicesRequired;
            int verificationsRequired;
            int areasRequired;
            int subscriptionsRequired;
            int numServices = 0;
            int numAreas = 0;
            int numVerifications = 0;
            int numSubscriptions = 0;

            MajorID = UserInfo.intMajorID;
            var releaseStatus = form.ReleasedStatus;

            if (form.OperatorBusinessUnitID != null)
            {
                businessUnitID = form.OperatorBusinessUnitID;
            }
            if (form.Services != null)
            {
                numServices = form.Services.Count;
            }

            servicesRequired = form.ServicesRequired;
            areasRequired = form.AreasRequired;
            verificationsRequired = form.VerificationsRequired;
            subscriptionsRequired = form.SubscriptionsRequired;
            if (form.Areas != null)
            {
                numAreas = form.Areas.Count;

            }
            if (form.Verifications != null)
            {
                numVerifications = form.Verifications.Count;

            }
            if (form.Subscriptions != null)
            {
                numSubscriptions = form.Subscriptions.Count;

            }
            if (businessUnitID != 0)
            {
                strSqlQuery = " INNER JOIN tblAscOperatorBusinessUnitToContractors (READUNCOMMITTED) BUTC ON C.CompanyID = BUTC.ContractorID AND BUTC.OperatorBusinessUnitID = " + businessUnitID;

            }
            #region Add Services
            if (numServices != 0)
            {

                int[] services = new int[numServices];
                i = 0;
                foreach (var item in form.Services)
                {
                    services[i] = item;
                    i++;
                }
                    strServices = services[0].ToString();
                if(numServices > 1)
                {
                    for (i = 1; i < numServices; i++)
                    {
                        string myservice = services[i].ToString();
                        strServices = strServices + "," + myservice;
                    }
                    strServices = "(" + strServices + ")";
                }
                if (servicesRequired == 1)
                {
                    if (numServices == 1)
                    {
                        strServices = "Select tm1.ContractorID from (select distinct tblServiceMatrix.ContractorID, ServiceID from tblServiceMatrix group by ContractorID, ServiceID) as tm1 " +
                                        "WHERE tm1.ServiceID=" + strServices.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strServices = "Select tm1.ContractorID from (select distinct tblServiceMatrix.ContractorID, ServiceID from tblServiceMatrix group by ContractorID, ServiceID) as tm1 " +
                     "WHERE tm1.ServiceID in" + strServices + " Group By ContractorID Having count(*)=" + numServices.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    strServices = "Select tm1.ContractorID from (select distinct tblServiceMatrix.ContractorID, ServiceID from tblServiceMatrix group by ContractorID, ServiceID) as tm1 " +
                     "WHERE tm1.ServiceID in" + strServices;
                }
                strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " INNER JOIN (" + strServices + ") tm2 on C.CompanyID = tm2.ContractorID";
            }
            #endregion

            #region Add Areas
            if (numAreas != 0)
            {

                int[] areas = new int[numAreas];
                i = 0;
                foreach (var item in form.Areas)
                {
                    areas[i] = item;
                    i++;
                }

                 strAreas = areas[0].ToString();
                if(numAreas > 1)
                {
                    for (i = 1; i < numAreas; i++)
                    {
                        string myarea = areas[i].ToString();
                        strAreas = strAreas + "," + myarea;
                    }
                    strAreas = "(" + strAreas + ")";

                }

                if (areasRequired == 1)
                {
                    if (numAreas == 1)
                    {
                        strAreas = "Select sm1.CompanyID from (select distinct tblAscCompanyToStates.CompanyID, StateVchID from tblAscCompanyToStates group by CompanyID, StateVchID) as sm1 " +
                                   "WHERE tm1.StateVchID='" + strAreas + "'";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strAreas = "Select sm1.CompanyID from (select distinct tblAscCompanyToStates.CompanyID, StateVchID from tblAscCompanyToStates group by CompanyID, StateVchID) as sm1 " +
                     "WHERE tm1.StateVchID in" + strAreas + " Group By CompanyID Having count(*)=" + numAreas.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    strAreas = "Select sm1.CompanyID from (select distinct tblAscCompanyToStates.CompanyID, StateVchID from tblAscCompanyToStates group by CompanyID, StateVchID) as sm1 " +
                     "WHERE tm1.StateVchID in" + strAreas;
                }

                strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " INNER JOIN (" + strAreas + ") sm2 on C.CompanyID = sm2.CompanyID";
            }

            #endregion

            #region Add Verifications

            if (numVerifications != 0)
            {

                int[] verifications = new int[numVerifications];
                i = 0;
                foreach (var item in form.Verifications)
                {
                    verifications[i] = item;
                    i++;
                }

                strVerifications = verifications[0].ToString();

                if(numVerifications > 1)
                {
                    for (i = 1; i < numVerifications; i++)
                    {
                        string myverification = verifications[i].ToString();
                        strVerifications = strVerifications + "," + myverification;
                    }
                    strVerifications = "(" + strVerifications + ")";
                }

                if (verificationsRequired == 1)
                {
                    if (numVerifications == 1)
                    {
                        strVerifications = "Select ContractorID from tblSSQVerifications inner join tblverificationtypestates on tblSSQVerifications.VerificationTypeStateID = " +
                                            "tblVerificationTypeStates.VerificationTypeStateID and tblVerificationTypeStates.isVerified = 1 inner join tblVerificationTypes on tblSSQVerifications.VerificationTypeID = tblVerificationTypes.VerificationTypeID " +
                                            "where tblSSQVerifications.bitActive = 1 and tblSSQVerifications.VerificationTypeID =" + strVerifications;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strVerifications = "select ContractorID from tblSSQVerifications inner join tblverificationtypestates on tblSSQVerifications.VerificationTypeStateID = " +
                                            "tblVerificationTypeStates.VerificationTypeStateID and tblVerificationTypeStates.isVerified = 1 inner join tblVerificationTypes on tblSSQVerifications.VerificationTypeID = tblVerificationTypes.VerificationTypeID " +
                                            "where tblSSQVerifications.bitActive = 1 and tblSSQVerifications.VerificationTypeID in" + strVerifications + " Group By ContractorID Having Count(*) =" +
                                            numVerifications.ToString(); ;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    strVerifications = "select ContractorID from tblSSQVerifications inner join tblverificationtypestates on tblSSQVerifications.VerificationTypeStateID = " +
                                        "tblVerificationTypeStates.VerificationTypeStateID and tblVerificationTypeStates.isVerified = 1 inner join tblVerificationTypes on tblSSQVerifications.VerificationTypeID = tblVerificationTypes.VerificationTypeID " +
                                        "where tblSSQVerifications.bitActive = 1 and tblSSQVerifications.VerificationTypeID in" + strVerifications;
                }

                strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " INNER JOIN (" + strVerifications + ") vt1 on C.CompanyID = vt1.ContractorID";
            }
            #endregion

            #region Add Subscriptions

            if (numSubscriptions != 0)
            {

                int[] subscriptions = new int[numSubscriptions];
                i = 0;
                foreach (var item in form.Subscriptions)
                {
                    subscriptions[i] = item;
                    i++;
                }

                strSubscriptions = subscriptions[0].ToString();
                if(numSubscriptions > 1)
                {

                    for (i = 1; i < numSubscriptions; i++)
                    {
                        string mysubscription = subscriptions[i].ToString();
                        strSubscriptions = strSubscriptions + "," + mysubscription;
                    }
                    strSubscriptions = "(" + strSubscriptions + ")";
                }

                if (subscriptionsRequired == 1)
                {
                    if (numSubscriptions == 1)
                    {
                        strSubscriptions = "select ContractorID from tblCompanySubscriptions inner join tblSubscriptionTypes on tblCompanySubscriptions.SubscriptionTypeID = " +
                                            "tblSubscriptionTypes.SubscriptionTypeID where tblCompanySubscriptions.SubscriptionTypeID = " + strSubscriptions;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strSubscriptions = "select ContractorID from tblCompanySubscriptions inner join tblSubscriptionTypes on tblCompanySubscriptions.SubscriptionTypeID = " +
                                            "tblSubscriptionTypes.SubscriptionTypeID where tblCompanySubscriptions.SubscriptionTypeID IN" + strSubscriptions + " GROUP BY ContractorID Having Count(*)=" + numSubscriptions.ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    strSubscriptions = "select ContractorID from tblCompanySubscriptions inner join tblSubscriptionTypes on tblCompanySubscriptions.SubscriptionTypeID = " +
                                            "tblSubscriptionTypes.SubscriptionTypeID where tblCompanySubscriptions.SubscriptionTypeID IN" + strSubscriptions;
                }
                strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " INNER JOIN (" + strSubscriptions + ") sb on C.CompanyID = sb.ContractorID";
            }

            #endregion

            #region Add Static
            strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " LEFT JOIN tblTrainingRelease TR on C.CompanyID = TR.ContractorID and TR.OperatorID = " + MajorID + " AND TR.bitContractorRelease = 1 and TR.bitReleaseGranted = 1 " +
                            " LEFT JOIN tblSSQReleaseToMajor (READUNCOMMITTED) ON C.CompanyID = RT.CompanyID AND RT.MajorID = " + MajorID + " WHERE 1 = 1";


            #endregion

            #region Add Name Search
            if (form.Company != null)
            {
                strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " AND ((C.vchCompanyName like '%" + form.Company + "%') OR (isnull(C.vchFIDNumber, '') like '%" + form.Company + "%') OR (convert(varchar(16), C.CompanyID) like '%" + form.Company + "%'))";

            }

            #endregion

            #region Add Company Type

            if (form.CompanyType != null)
            {
                strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " AND C.CompanyTypeID = " + form.CompanyType;

            }
            else
            {
                strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " AND ((CASE WHEN C.CompanyTypeID in ( 16,32,256,512,2048,8388608) THEN 8+32 " +
                 "WHEN C.CompanyTypeID in ( 2048,8192,16384,8388608) THEN 4096+16384 ELSE 0 END)!= 0 ) ";
            }

            #endregion

            #region Add Release Status
            switch (releaseStatus)
            {
                case 1:
                    strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " AND (RT.BitwiseSSQReleaseStatus & (1+8+512)) = (1+8+512) AND ISNULL(C.bitActive,0) = 1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " AND (((RT.BitwiseSSQReleaseStatus & (1)) != (1)) AND ( (RT.BitwiseSSQReleaseStatus & (4)) = (4)))";
                    break;

            }


            #endregion
            strSqlQuery = strSqlQuery + " ORDER BY c.vchCompanyName";
            var results = SearchClient.PostGeneralSearch(strSqlQuery,1000,1);


            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: please share more code. this is purely depend on the way you have implement it. otherwise get search will execute only once you initiate the controller

Comment: I did as you asked.  Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: if you share controller you can define a constant on your home page only saying `window.isHomePage = true`, though this is kinda smelly. Try factoring out separate logic/rules into different controllers.

Comment: feels like you have mixed MVC way of doing things and angular way of doing things. don't mix these two. still im unable to give some answer because not clear on the situation. as 2ooom suggest try to refactor the code to separate controllers. this always matters how and where you initiate the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is really abstract.  Here's my solution (based upon your input).
I assume the controller you use for post back is Submit().  You may set a ViewBag variable which can be used to test for postback.  Then you just test for postback in your javascript.  (but honestly, i'd rather do SPA)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit()
{
    ViewBag.IsPostBack true;
    return View();
}
```